# Can't search for tweets with LinqToTwitter

Tags: c#, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I'm starting out a new c# project where I want to extract some tweets, nothing specific at the moment, just to get started...

I created a developer user at the Twitter API and created a new app and got all the consumerkey and accesstoken...

According to this link - https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter/wiki/Single-User-Authorization
Everything should work fairly smooth but I just don't get any results...

My project is a .net console application and this is my code which is almost copy-paste from the reference I mentioned above:

```
var auth = new SingleUserAuthorizer
{
    CredentialStore = new SingleUserInMemoryCredentialStore
    {
        ConsumerKey = ...,
        ConsumerSecret = ...,
        AccessToken = ...,
        AccessTokenSecret = ...
    }
};


var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth);

var searchResponse =
    (from search in twitterCtx.Search
     where search.Type == SearchType.Search &&
           search.Query == "\"LINQ to Twitter\""
     select search)
    .SingleOrDefault();

if (searchResponse != null && searchResponse.Statuses != null)
    searchResponse.Statuses.ForEach(tweet =>
        Console.WriteLine(
            "User: {0}, Tweet: {1}",
            tweet.User.ScreenNameResponse,
            tweet.Text));
```

I don't even know how to identify if the authentication process was successful, 
Any assistance please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the `await` on the search query:

```
var searchResponse =
    await
    (from search in twitterCtx.Search
     where search.Type == SearchType.Search &&
           search.Query == "\"LINQ to Twitter\""
     select search)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

LINQ to Twitter is `async`, which means that all methods in the call chain must be `async` and you must `await` calls. What is probably happening is that the method returns before the `searchResponse` is populated and you don't see results. Adding the `await` makes the code wait for the response.